# Firebase .OrderByChild() not working for boolean values

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am running a query in the nodes to be returned are to be ordered by a field containing a boolean value. According to the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data)

> orderByChild
>
> When using orderByChild(), data that contains the specified child key
>   is ordered as follows:
>
> 1. Children with a null value for the specified child key come first.
> 2. Children with a value of false for the specified child key come next.
>      If multiple children have a value of false, they are sorted
>      lexicographically by key.
> 3. Children with a value of true for the
>      specified child key come next. If multiple children have a value of
>      true, they are sorted lexicographically by key.

Below is the JSON structure of the tree which I am using

```
  "boolsTest" : {
    "node1" : {
      "truthValue" : true
    },
    "node2" : {
      "truthValue" : false
    },
    "node3" : {
      "truthValue" : true
    }
  }
```

I then run a query on the tree as shown below

```
      await admin.database().ref(`boolsTest`).orderByChild("truthValue").once('value').then((value) =>{
          console.log("The values retuned by the query: " + JSON.stringify(value));
          return value;
  }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("The error returned: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      return error
  })
  })
```

What results are the elements of the tree returned unordered, in the order of

> The values retuned by the query: {"node1":{"truthValue":true},"node2":{"truthValue":false},"node3":{"truthValue":true}}

Why are my values not being ordered and how do I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Please replace the data structure with the actual, literal JSON as text (no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for taking the time to look into this issue. I have added the edits of the JSON structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query/ordered read against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

The result you get back from the database contains three things:

1. The value of each matching node
2. The key of each matching node
3. The order in which the nodes are within the result

When you call `.val()` on a snapshot it converts these three pieces of information to a JSON object. And the order of keys within a JSON object is undefined, so the conversion loses the order information. So when you treat the entire result as one big JSON object (as your code does), you lose information about the order.

To prevent this, you should use `Snapshot.forEach()` to loop over the results:

```
await admin.database().ref(`boolsTest`).orderByChild("truthValue").once('value').then((snapshot) =>{
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    console.log("Value retuned by the query: " + JSON.stringify(childSnapshot.val()));
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for  taking the time to write such a great answer. It makes sense the query returns a JSON array and must be treated as an array. Your answer  works exactly as expected I greatly appreciate your help. GO FIREBASE!!!!

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, Im noticing that when I add in `.limitToLast(3)` after `orderByChild()` the order doesn't seem to be correct either even with the solution. Furthermore I am noticing the same thing with `.limitToFirst(3)`. Is there any reason that adding `.limitToLast(3)` should prevent any kind of ordering from occurring?**(I apologize I deleted the previous comment I meant `.limitToLast(3)`)

Comment: Nope, putting a limit on the query does not change the order, since limits are applied last (after ordering, and other filters). So there must be something else going wrong. Be sure to use `snapshot.forEach()` as `snapshot.val()` won't be ordered (since the order of keys in a JSON object is undefined).